# Making AutoCompleteTextView Drop Down NOT Clickable

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an `autocompletetextview` where the user types, and a drop down menu populates.  In this case, I am showing the user that a particular item name is used and therefore NOT available to be selected.  I'd like to show the drop-down but make it NON-clickable?  Is this possible?

This may not be relevant but it retrieves data from online database.   I basically attach the word `"Used: " + myString` and that is what populates.

Edit:

Here is adapter:

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dialog_dropdown_list,
                    itemList);

          etInsertAutoComplete.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: can you show what does the adapter for the dropdown look like?

Comment: @Varun added the requested code.

Comment: You can extend a `BaseAdapter` and choose which items are clickable by overriding methods.. Override `areAllItemsEnabled ()` and return false; and also override this `public boolean isEnabled (int position)` and return `true/false` as needed.

Comment: And if you are looking to make a `ListView` that has headers kind of stuff, you might want to look into `ExpandableListView`. You can see `APIDemos` for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am too late for this answer.But this will help you out.
For that you have to implement custom adapter by extend BaseAdapter.
autocompleteTextview gets value using adapter.getItem(position) using the method `performCompletion`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#performCompletion()

```
private void performCompletion(View selectedView, int position, long id) {
    if (isPopupShowing()) {
        Object selectedItem;
        if (position < 0) {
            selectedItem = mPopup.getSelectedItem();
        } else {
           selectedItem = mAdapter.getItem(position); // It will null if we return null in getItem() method of an adapter

        }
        if (selectedItem == null) {
            return;
        }
}
```

dropdown will receive item click by following code,

```
@Override
     public Object getItem(int position)
      {
        return itemList.get(position).getName();
      }
```

To make it not clickable simply return null,

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

It will show the dropdown list but item will not be clickable.